# Dynamic value in array doesn't apply in html?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, polymer

I have an array of objects, 4 objects, each objects contains 7 data holders. Some of the data is used to style elements in Polymer 0.9, the corresponding data is changed upon AJAX call, but they don't update the styles of elements...

variable declaration:

```
info: {
        type: Array,
        notify: true,
        value: [
            { centar: "color: #9E9E9E;", *SOME OBJECTS* },
            { centar: "color: #9E9E9E;", *SOME OBJECTS* },
            { centar: "color: #9E9E9E;", *SOME OBJECTS* },
            { centar: "color: #9E9E9E;", *SOME OBJECTS* },
        ]
    }
```

JS:

```
infoLoaded: function(e){
    this.infoRAW = e.detail.response;

    for (i = 0; i < this.infoRAW.length; i++) { 
        this.info[i].centar = this.centarColor(this.infoRAW[i].skicentar.toLowerCase());
        this.info[i].brojstaza = this.infoRAW[i].brojstaza;
        this.info[i].temperatura = this.infoRAW[i].temperatura;
        this.info[i].vrijeme = this.infoRAW[i].vrijeme;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{info}}">
<paper-material z="1" class="chip" hero-id="{{item.planina}}" hero?="{{selectedPlanina === item}}">
    <div class="chip-top" style$="{{item.color}}" hero-id="{{item.planina}}-art" hero?="{{selectedPlanina === planina}}"></div>
    <div class="chip-bottom">
        <div class="chip-planina">{{item.planina}}</div>
        <div class="chip-centar">Centar <i class="fa fa-circle" style$="{{info.centar}}"></i></div>
    </div>
</paper-material>
```

the `style$="{{info.centar}}"` does not change upon ajax completion, but the console log on `this.info.centar` shows that the value has changed..

help?

EDIT #1

I've fixed it! For anyone assigning values to array and using them as dynamic, instead of using:

```
this.info[i].brojstaza = this.infoRAW[i].brojstaza;
```

use:

```
var path = "info."+i;
this.set(path+".brojstaza", this.infoRAW[i].brojstaza);
```

Comment: also the observer for value change on the array declared in the properties is not called upon any kind of value change in the array